# Stream text response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, stream, java-stream

We have a spring service that fetch large set of data from DB and stream end to end to controller.
For JSON format we are directly returning Java Stream :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Stream<Entity>> getJSONData()
```

We have trouble to have same behavior for CSV format, when we try

```
@GetMapping(value = "/csv", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Stream<String>> getCSVData()
```

we get : `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head] with preset Content-Type 'text/plain'`

Is there a way to achieve this by directly returning a Stream of text like for Json ?
PS : we want to avoid the usage of StreamingResponseBody as it's async

Comment: Have you tried `InputStreamResource`?

Comment: I didn't find a clean way to go from Stream (this is what we get from database) to InputStreamResource without breaking the stream with foreach